# position of text relative to another element in SVG

Tags: svg

I think I'm doing this the hard way... I have ~200 circles that need to have text in the middle of them (atomic structures in svg).  What I've been doing is offsetting the next by typing in the absolute positional value of each text offset by 5.2 from the circle it's in,

```
<circle id="H4_11_" class="st3" cx="1660.8" cy="714.5" r="10"/>
<use xlink:href="#hydrogen_label" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1655.6 719.7)" />
```

Is there a way to just position the text relative to the first one by placing each circle in it's own container?  Something like,

```
<g>
     <circle id="H4_11_" class="st3" cx="1660.8" cy="714.5" r="10"/>
     <use xlink:href="#hydrogen_label" transform="(+5.2,-5.2)" />
</g>
```

Tried the above and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure things like this perhaps so that the local co-ordinate system is set in the `<g>`.

```
<g transform="translate(1660.8, 714.5)">
     <circle id="H4_11_" class="st3" r="10"/>
     <use xlink:href="#hydrogen_label" transform="translate(-5.2, 5.2)" />
</g>
```